# Need help fixing file / directory ownership using ISPConfig

Tags: permissions, apache2, groups

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 and ISPConfig 3.1 following this official guide here: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-16.04-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/

Everything is working as expected, but I'm running into a file / directory ownership issue. To explain the issue, I need to write an example:

- User uploads a PHP script that allows website visitors to upload images to `/images/`.
- User must chmod `/images/` 0777 or the PHP script will return a permission denied error when some visitor tries to upload an image.

When inspecting the contents of the `/images/`directory with `ls -l images`, it returns:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 69455 Dec 12 13:03 755675678.tmp
```

The .tmp file in this case is a file uploaded with chmod 0777. It suggests that the script is executed by www-data.

However, when inspecting the directory itself with `ls -l`, it returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 web1 client1  4096 Dec 12 13:03 images
```

So that explains why the directory would need to be 0777 for www-data to be able to write to it. Doing some further investigation though, I've checked the client1 group with:

`getent group client1 | awk -F: '{print $4}'` and it returns: www-data

At this point I'm lost. I'm still very new to Linux and Ubuntu. I don't understand how groups and members of those groups work. But it would seem logical to me that www-data would have all the permissions required because it's a member of client1. I could be completely wrong about this though, so if anyone could explain me why I'm running into this problem and how to fix it, I'd be very gratefull :)

Comment: the group permissions are -xr, that means read and execute only. the folder permissions need to be 0772 to give group write permission.

Comment: @ravery Yes, terdon was actually just explaining me that. I assumed the group was automaticly owner of the folder as well. But that was wrong as I now understand :)

Comment: folder permissions **0777** are hardcoded in PHP script? Allowing `nobody` to write to the folder is very unsecure.

Comment: @M.Dm. No they are not. Please read the question again. I think you misunderstood it

Comment: So if anyone would like to provide a meaningfull answer to this question, please explain that groups aren't the owner of a folder. That's why chmod 0755 wouldn't work. To solve the issue, I have to provide permissions to the group instead (0775).